# Penetration depth of gamma rays in liquid Xenon

Tags: particle-physics, radiation

This is not a homework problem. I am trying to understand what the graph below can tell me about the "distance" a gamma ray of energy $E$ MeV will travel in liquid Xenon

[image: attenuation range of Xenon]

A second useful graph may be

[image: stopping power of xenon]

Comment: Where is this graph from? Can you send us a link?

Comment: You need to look up the density of liquid xenon to convert the y-axis value to an attenuation length.

Comment: Pieter: Density of liquid xenon is 2.942 $g/cm^3$, link to source: https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/ElemTab/z54.html

Comment: Am I to interpret the Y axis as follows: gamma rays loose energy equal to $\mu/ \rho × \rho_{aq}$ MeV per cm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variables are explained [earlier in the NIST data sheet](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/chap2.html) ([table of contents](https://www.nist.gov/pml/x-ray-mass-attenuation-coefficients)).

The x-axis of this graph is the energy in MeV of the gamma photon penetrating the material. The y-axis gives the attenuation rate of the photon beam in historically idiosyncratic units. The attenuation rate gives the fraction of gamma beam energy intensity (W/m$^2$) remaining after penetrating a given distance into a material. Mathematically,
$$I(t) = I_0e^{-(\mu/\rho)\rho t},$$
where $t$ is the thickness of the material, $I(t)$ is the intensity of the gamma beam after penetrating a distance $t$ into the material, and the $\mu/\rho$ data is the attenuation distance $\mu$ scaled by the material density $\rho$. This data does not give energy loss per distance (MeV/cm) in the same way that particle stopping power charts do.

The data is presented in the strange $\mu/\rho$ way because, back when these tables were first being compiled, it was found that dividing the attenuation length ($\mu$) by the density ($\rho$) resulted in most materials having a similar range of values. This made for easy plotting and the realization that for shielding, what matters is getting enough mass between the radiation source and whatever needs protecting. Less dense materials require a greater thickness to provide the same shielding as less dense materials.

The quanitiy $\mu_{en}$ is the rate of energy absorption by the material. This is less than the energy loss by the gamma photons because--especially at higher energies--energy lost by the primary gamma photons is lost from the material as secondary radiation (ionized electrons, lower energy photons, etc.).

---

The second graph showing stopping power does allow for the caclulation of the energy loss per distance traveled (MeV/cm after multiplying the y-axis value by the density of the material). You can estimate the stopping distance using ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopping_power_(particle_radiation))):
$$\Delta x = \int_0^{E_0} \frac{dE}{S(E)}$$
where $\Delta x$ is the mean penetrating distance, $E$ is the particle's energy, $E_0$ is the particle's starting energy, and $S(E)$ is the (non-mass-scaled) stopping power at the given energy.

Comment: Would the second graph in my edited question suffice?

Comment: @VincentHaugdahl Updated.

Comment: Mark H as an example, assume the grapf is a straight line from $x=0$ to $x=0.15$ given by $L(x)$, further assume that the initial energy of the gamma ray is $0.15$ MeV, to get the penetration length I would just need to use your formula above and integrate $\int_0^{0.15} \frac{1}{L(x)} dx$?

Comment: @VincentHaugdahl As long as $x$ is the energy of the particle, you have it right.